# How to disable Thunderbird AUTO UPDATE?

Tags: settings, preferences, auto-update, thunderbird, disable

How can I disable the AUTO UPDATE process/function automatically used/applied by the (Mozilla) Thunderbird=**TB** (email-client) app? For example, in v68 series: v68.12.0 or v68.12.1, etc.?

What settings/preferences change are needed?  Please show different options to disable auto-update.

Currently (at the time of writing this post) TB's last version is v78 series, it is using built in RNP based OpenPGP features, instead of GPG. TB version v68 series uses GPG based external-tools instead of built in OpenPGP features, of course GPG follows OpenPGP standards. I need to use GPG based tools, for now.

And, if TB automatically updates from v68 series (v68.12.0 or v68.12.1, etc) version into v78 series or later version (v78.4.0, etc.), then downgrading (from v78 series back into v68 series) sometimes is very complicated (or sometime not possible without data loss), if sufficient backup not-made, etc.

Info from TB v78 release notes<sup>[1](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/78.0/releasenotes/)</sup>:

- *Address books are now stored as SQLite databases to prepare for future addressbook improvements. Existing address books in MAB format (using a Mork database) will be converted.*
- *TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled*

So, I want to avoid that **"auto update"** process, for now.

If I need to, or when I will need to, then I myself can manually select button in TB's GUI to check for updates, and then I can click on "Update" to force an update process, but otherwise, it (TB) must not AUTO UPDATE.

And, during installation of (Mozilla) Thunderbird = TB, it did not obtain my consent to do auto-update of TB in my computer. It can check for update & can also SHOW me NEW VERSION NUMBER, and can also WARN me to update. BUT IT MUST ASK ME FIRST, before running ANY update. TB/FF, etc apps MUST NOT act like they are the owner of the computer where the app is used/running, TB/FF, etc. app must follow+respect my/user's choice/preferences in my/user's computer.

Comment: Maybe this new question should not have been asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78040197/how-to-disable-thunderbird-update-request

Comment: @tadeus: Neither question is on-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Disable the auto-update (or app update) process used by (mozilla) Thunderbird = **TB**, email-client software, and Firefox = **FF**, web-browser software.

TB = Thunderbird . FF = Firefox.

in below,
if you'll configure TB only, then avoid following config/setting that are for FF.
if you'll configure FF only, then avoid following config/setting that are for TB.

### DISABLE AUTO-UPDATE VIA CONFIG SETTINGS IN THUNDERBIRD/FIREFOX GUI:

Disable auto update via Thunderbird's (or Firefox's) GUI (graphical user interfacce):

- `"about:preferences"` - goto TB/FF's main menu > `Preferences` (in macOS) , or goto TB/FF main menu > `Options` (in Windows) , or goto TB/FF main menu > `Tools` > `Options` (in Windows), or goto TB main menu > `Options` (in Linux/Unix).

  - in macOS goto **"Update"** tab: in left-pane/rows, select `"Advanced"` > then in right-side select `"Update"` tab
  - in Windows, Linux/Unix goto **"Update"** tab or section: select `"General"` in left-pane/rows > then in right-side select `"Update"` tab or scroll-down to the `"Update"` section.
- select this specific option:
  **◉**`"check for updates, but let me choose whether to install them"`.
  [image: Thunderbird - Preferences - Advanced - Update]
- if you see such option:
  **☐**`“Use a background service to install updates”` exists
  or has-appeared, under this below option
  **◉**`"Check for updates, but let you choose to install them"`,
  then keep the "background-service" option also unchecked/unselected (**☐**).

  - if this "background-service" option is disabled, and when you will want to do update manually, then TB/FF will show you update pop-ups meesage, and ask you to decide if you want to install or cancel.
- if you goto "Update" tab or section, you should see info like below
  [image: Thunderbird - Update - Show History - version number]
  (shown version number will be different at different time)

### Here is DISABLE-UPDATE Recommended By Thunderbird:

[README.md#disableappupdate](https://github.com/thundernest/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#disableappupdate).

### DISABLE AUTO UPDATE VIA "ABOUT:CONFIG" = "CONFIG-EDITOR" IN THUNDERBIRD/FIREFOX:

Change below preference/options/settings, to disable update or auto-update:

- type `“about:config”` (without previous double-quote symbols) in a browser-tab address bar inside Thunderbird/Firefox , then press “Enter“,

  - or goto TB main-menu > Tools > Options , or goto TB's `Preferences`/settings , then goto `Advanced` > `General` > at bottom side you should see `"Config Editor"`.
- [image: Thunderbird - Pref - Adv - General - Config-Editor]
     Config-Editor is shown above in bottom-right corner.
- you have to agree "I accept the risk!" button shown in below, to proceed into editing stage of preference/setting
  [image: Thunderbird - Pref - Adv - General - Config-Editor - Risk Alert]
- in search box, type to search for this setting: `“app.update.auto”`
- double-click on the `“app.update.auto”` option to toggle/switch the setting in-between `"true"` or `"false"` .  If it is set to “true“, then automatic updates are enabled . If set to “false“, automatic updates are disabled.
  [image: Thunderbird - Pref - Adv - General - Config-Editor - app.update.auto]
- search for `"app.update.enabled"` setting, if exists and if it is not showing `false`, then change `true` by double-clicking on it into `false`, then any update will be disabled.

  - You may also create this setting if it does not exist, and then set it to `false` anyway.
  - when `"app.update.enabled"` is `false` (any update is disabled), then TB/FF will also ignore the `“app.update.auto”` setting/option even if its `true`.
- search for `"app.update.silent"` setting: if it exists and if you set it to `true`, then TB/FF will not show you reminder message when new update is available. If it is `fasle`, then TB will show you update notification, and you have to choose if you want to update or not.

  - this setting should be set to `true`, so that TB/FF can atleast notify you when a newer update is available, as some updates are really helpful.
  - I like this option, as it informs me when a new update available & (new) version number of that. Then i like to Cancel this update notification myself, so i keep at `false`. My Mac/PC is not used by anyone else, so there is (almost) no-chance that someone in my side can select such an option to update it.  I'm always careful about updating anything.
- search for `"app.update.doorhanger"` setting: if it exists and if you set it to `false`, then TB/FF will not show you notifying icon or reminder message, even when a new update is available.

  - [image]
  - [image: Thunderbird - Doorhanger Notifications]
- if your PC/Mac is used also by someone else, or if there is a chance that you may mistakenly choose "Update" (or you forget to NOT-update), then it is better that you disable all update & notification by doing these: keep `“app.update.auto”` at `false`, `"app.update.silent"` at `true`, `"app.update.enabled"` at `fasle`, `"app.update.doorhanger"` at `false`.
- WHEN A SETTING DOES NOT PRE-EXIST, THEN HOW DO I ADD IT MANUALLY ? create it manually this way : type any word, for-example "doorhanger" in "Search" box, then right-click on empty area below "Preference Name" column, or right click on the column header "Preference Name" > popup window will appear, select "New" . As the `"app.update.doorhanger"` setting can only have value `false` or `true`, so it is a "Boolean" type setting, so select "New" > "Boolean" , then enter preference name `"app.update.doorhanger"` > then select "false" or "true" value, based on what YOU want it to perform.
- More info:
  [http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_Entries#Update._and_Update_notifications](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3Aconfig_Entries#Update._and_Update_notifications)
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security_Policies

### DISABLE AUTO UPDATE VIA "REGEDIT" IN WINDOWS:

In windows, if you want to make sure, Thunderbird app update is completely disabled, then for both 64bit & 32bit Windows or TB, follow below steps:

- run `regedit.exe`, ( reg =registry ) , accept the RISK related warnings, and find/browse to below reg key location:
  • `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Thunderbird` (for Thunderbird=TB).
  or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Thunderbird` (for Thunderbird=TB).
  • `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox` (for Firefox=FF).
  [image: RegEdit - Windows - Thunderbird - Policy - DisableAppUpdate]
- If any one of the above/below (Thunderbird related) reg keys does not exist in Windows Registry, then Create them with a right-click on the previous key (for example: "Mozilla"), and then select `New` > `Key` > specify key name (for example: "Thunderbird" or "Firefox"), then right-click on the key `Thunderbird` to configure TB, or, right-click on key `Firefox` to configure FF , and again select `New` > `Dword` (32-bit) Value > name it `DisableAppUpdate` > set its value to `1` to disable TB/FF app update & auto-update.
  ( If later you want-to/need-to enable app update, then you may set `DisableAppUpdate` key value to `0`. )
- After above setting is done, user will see a line
  ***"Updates disabled by your system administrator"***
  has appeared under the version number, in Thunderbird, and such line will also appear in TB main-menu > `"About"` popup info page, and inside `"Update"` tab or under `"Update"` section, etc.
  [image: Thunderbird - Update - disabled by system admin]
- if you want to disable only AUTO UPDATE (not TB/FF app update/upgrade), then create/goto below reg entry & set your preferred value:
  • goto/create `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Thunderbird\AppAutoUpdate` for TB, and set value to `0` . To enable auto-update use value `1`.
  • goto/create `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\AppAutoUpdate` for FF, and set value to `0` . To enable auto-update, use value `1`.
- if you prefer to NOT update extensions/addons, then create this reg entry:
  • goto/create `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Thunderbird\ExtensionUpdate` for TB, and set it's value to `0` . To allow extnsn/addon update set value to `1`.
  • goto/create `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\ExtensionUpdate` for FF, and set it's value to `0` . To allow extsn/addon update set value to `1`.

In newer TB versions, above settings may be ignored, and OS other-than Windows-OS does not use Windows-REGISTRY, so, to make sure that update or auto-update is completely disabled in Linux/Unix/macOS, you have to apply POLICY RULE based solution.
TB = Thunderbird . FF = Firefox.
OS = Operating System (for example: Windows, macOS, Linux, Unix, Android, iOS, etc).

### UNHIDE THE HIDDEN FILES/FOLDERS:

Users who can't view/see the files/folders mentioned in below, those users can use below commands to **UNHIDE** the HIDDEN files/folders:
• in macOS > start "Finder" app , "Finder" is very similar to Windows-"Explorer" > in Finder, in left side/pane, select "Applications" > then scroll down & go into "Utilities" subfolder > then click on "Terminal" or "Terminal.app" to start it.
• type below command inside "Terminal" ( macOS "Terminal" is like Windows "Command-Prompt")**:**
`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true`
• then you must reboot Mac-computer OR run below command:
`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`
or, run just this: `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/killall Finder`
or, just this: `sudo killall Finder`
then all hidden files+folders will by-default be shown to user in macOS Finder. **)**
• in Windows, start/open windows "File Explorer" (aka "Explorer", aka "Windows Explorer") from the taskbar , select "View" > "Options" > change folder and search options : select the "View" tab and, in "Advanced" settings, select "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" > and also select "Show File name extensions" > then "OK".

in macOS, inside any file browsing window, user can also press below THREE buttons altogether ONCE, to show HIDDEN files/folders:
[Command**⌘**] + [Shift**⇧**] + [**.**<sup>></sup>]
if user press-es above three buttons again, file-browsing-window will HIDE the HIDDEN files/folders.

By default in macOS, "Finder" will keep most of the file's extension hidden . But we need to see all File's extension, so we can be sure & not make mistake . To view all file's extension, do below steps:
in macOS > start "Finder" app > goto main menu > Finder > Preferences > Advanced > select `"Show All Filename Extensions"` option.

### DISABLE AUTO UPDATE VIA CHANGING THUNDERBIRD UPDATE POLICIES:

For TB/FF version v62 & later, and TB/FF ESR v60 & later, please read essential instruction on policies that any OS user first need-to understand, [here](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md).

- Windows - locate the sub-folder where your `"thunderbird.exe"` (or `"firefox.exe"`) file is, then create a sub-folder called `"distribution"` next to the EXE file, then create a file `"policies.json"` inside the `"distribution\"` sub-folder.

  - `"thunderbird.exe"` file/app is usually located here:
    `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\"` (if you're using 64bit edition)
    `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\"` (if you're using 32bit edition)
  - `"firefox.exe"` file/app is usually located here:
    `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"` (if you're using 64bit edition)
    `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"` (if you're using 32bit edition)
- macOS - go inside `"Thunderbird.app"`, (for which you want to disable update or disable auto-update), by right-clicking on `"Thunderbird.app"` icon/file, & then select `"Show Package Contents"` option, create a sub-folder `"distribution/"` inside the `"Resources/"` sub-folder, like this: `"Thunderbird.app/Contents/Resources/distribution/"`, then create a file called `"policies.json"` inside `"distribution/"` sub-folder.

  - go inside `"Firefox.app"` (for which you want to disable update or auto-update), by right-clicking on `"Firefox.app"` icon/file, & then select `"Show Package Contents"` option, create a sub-folder `"distribution/"` inside the `"Resources/"` sub-folder, like this: `"Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/distribution/"`, then create a file called `"policies.json"` inside `"distribution"` sub-folder.
  - Then follow from here: [1](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/tree/master/mac), [2](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md).
  - Note: `"Thunderbird.app"` (or `"Firefox.app"`) is usually located inside the `"Applications/"` folder, under the `"/"` root folder of Mac storage drive, here: `"/Applications/"`
- Linux/Unix - create the file `"policies.json"` inside `"distribution/"` folder, located here: `"thunderbird/distribution/"` for TB, (or create `"distribution/"` here `"firefox/distribution/"` for FF), different OS distro (aka: distribution) keeps the thunderbird (or firefox) app folder at different location, for-example: TB may be located here: `"/opt/thunderbird/"`, `"/usr/local/thunderbird/"`, etc. Same way, FF could also be in different location in different distro, for example, it can be here: `"/opt/firefox/"`, `"/usr/local/firefox/"`, etc.
- If you don't want to create the `"distribution/"` sub-folder inside TB/FF app folder, then you can also create or specify a system-wide policy by placing the json file here for TB: `/etc/thunderbird/policies/` (or place here for FF: `/etc/firefox/policies/`), in macOS/Linux/Unix.
- create a policy rule inside the `"policies.json"` file, (as shown inside above linked webpages, and also shown in below code/quote box), to disable auto-update use below policy rule:

> ```
> {
>   "policies": {
>     "AppAutoUpdate": false
>   }
> }
> ```

- to disable/stop application update completely, use below policy rule:

> ```
> {
>   "policies": {
>       "DisableAppUpdate": true
>   }
> }
> ```

- if you use `"DisableAppUpdate"` policy rule, then specifying `"AppAutoUpdate"` is not needed. When `"DisableAppUpdate"` rule is `true`, then auto-update will be automatically disabled (turned-off).
- when you will update TB/FF manually or when you will install newer updated TB/FF version manually, then this JSON file will be deleted, so keep a backup somewhere. When you finish update manually, then copy-paste `"policies.json"` again inside `"distribution/"` sub-folder (inside TB/FF app working folder), if you don't want the newer version to auto-update or update, without your approval or permission.
- if you goto "Update" tab or section inside TB settings/Preferences/Options, then you should see info like below:
  ***"Updates disabled by your system administrator"***
  [image: Thunderbird - Update - disabled by system admin]
- to disable extension/addon update, use below policy rule:

> ```
> {
>   "policies": {
>       ...
>       "ExtensionUpdate": false
>       ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> the `...` in above is your other policy rules.

- More info:
  https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md

TB = Thunderbird . FF = Firefox.

### DISABLE AUTO UPDATE VIA CHANGING THUNDERBIRD "PREF.JS" CONFIG FILE:

For TB/FF version v62 & earlier, user would need-to & can do these changes:

- if TB/FF is running, then you may/can goto TB main-menu > `Help` > `Troubleshooting Information` > press Ctrl+F to find this word (or to find profile information row), type: `about:profiles` > click-on `about:profiles` link > write down the active **Root** & **Local** PROFILE folder/directory path name(s) , they will have the word `.default` at-end (or other PROFILE's name/word), write it down. If the information row has a `[ Browse ]` button, then press it to open-up the profile folder quickly, inside your OS's file-browser software.
- close/EXIT from Thunderbird=TB / Firefox=FF, if it is running.
- if you could-not follow the `"Troubleshooting Information"` step shown above (to reach the "profile" folder locaiton quickly), then follow these: browse/navigate to the following folder/directory location(s), based on your OS (operating system), to find & open TB/FF `"PROFILE"` folder/directory:

  - Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10 – for TB profile goto `“%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\“` (or `“%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Thunderbird\“`)
    or for FF profile goto `“%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\“` (or `“%APPDATA%\Mozilla\“`)
    • in newer Windows, `“%APPDATA%\“` env-var usually points to this folder/directory location: `“C:\Users\<WindowsUserName>\AppData\Roaming\“`
    • in WinXP/2000, `"%APPDATA%\"` points-to `"C:\Documents and Settings\<WindowsUserName>\Application Data\"`
    • `"%APPLOCALDATA%"` usually is `“C:\Users\<WindowsUserName>\AppData\Local\“` (it holds local data, cache data, etc)
  - Unix/Linux – for TB profile goto `“~/.thunderbird/“` , but different Linux/Unix distro (aka: distribution) may use different location, in some distro "profile" may also be here `“~/.mozilla-thunderbird-<profile-name>/“`
    • For FF profile, goto `“~/.mozilla/“`
    • the `“~“` symbol points-to `$HOME/` directory/folder, it is usually located here: `/Users/<YourLinuxOrUnixUserName>/`
  - macOS X / XI – for TB profile goto `“~/Library/Thunderbird/“` or `“~/Library/Application Support/Thunderbird/“`
    • for FF profile goto `“~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/“`
    • the `“~“` symbol indicating to your `$HOME/` directory/folder: `/Users/<YourMacOSUserName>/`
- open the **`“Profiles”`** sub-folder, to see all items under it.
- then open (aka: go-inside) the sub-folder that represents the "profile" that your TB/FF app is using. Name of this "profile" sub-folder will vary. Usually it begins with a bunch of alpha-numeric characters (often shown as `xxxxxxxx`) & followed-by or ends-with `“.default”` (or other `profile` name).

  - if you view files & folders sorted/based on `Date:Modified`, and if you go inside each sub-folders under the **`“Profiles”`** sub-folder, and if you compare last-modified date of item therein, you can realize which sub-folder was used last time & very recently by the TB/FF app that is the current/last TB/FF that got updated.
- open the `prefs.js` file inside "profile" (`"xxxxxxxx.<profile-name>"`) sub-folder, with a text editor like `Notepad++` (win), `TextMate` (mac), `gedit` (mac), etc.
- find the line inside the `pref.js` ("PREF.JS") file that contains `app.update.enabled`, if it doesn’t exist then add a line for it and set it as you want, with any one of the below line (but do-not use both lines):

  - automatic update enabled:
    `user_pref("app.update.enabled", true);`
  - automatic update disabled:
    `user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);`
- if you do not want AUTO new updates for Thunderbird (or Firefox) EXTENSIONS (aka: ADDONS), then find/add this `"extensions.update.enabled"` setting/preference line, inside `pref.js` file, if it does not already exists, & set it's value to `false`, as shown in below:

  - `user_pref("extensions.update.enabled", false);`
- if you do not want to show the `"Show Update History"` button, that is shown inside `"Update"` tab, inside TB's Preferences / Settings / Options, then add this `"disable_button.showUpdateHistory"` setting/preference line, inside `pref.js` file if it does not already exists, & set it's value to `false`, as shown in below:

  - `user_pref("app.update.disable_button.showUpdateHistory", false);`
- More info:
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_%2D_Thunderbird
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_%2D_Thunderbird
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Category%3AProfile_contents_%28Thunderbird%29
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_%2D_Firefox
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file
  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Show_hidden_files_and_folders

TB = Thunderbird . FF = Firefox.

### DELETE UPDATE-EXECUTABLE IF IT WAS AUTO-DOWNLOADED BY THUNDERBIRD:

Thunderbird=TB will auto download new updates/executables inside this/these below mentioned sub-folder(s), before you applied above settings, if TB has already obtained update, then remove it with below procedure:

- open file-browser, & browse/go to this sub-folder/directory:

  - macOS — check for TB `"updater"` file in these folders: `"/Users/<YourUserName>/Library/Thunderbird/updates/"`
    • or check for FF `"updater"` file in these folders: `"/Users/<YourUserName>/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/updates/"`
  - Windows XP,2000,Vista,7,8.1,10 — check for TB `"updater.exe"` file inside these folders: `“C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\“` , `“C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\updates\“` , `“%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\updates\“`
    • check for FF `"updater.exe"` file inside these folders: `“C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\“` , `“C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\updates\“` , `“%APPDATA%\Mozilla\updates\“` , `“%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\updates\“`
    • If you are using 32bit TB/FF then look additionally also inside this folder: `“C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\“` (or `“C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\“`)
  - Unix/Linux — look for TB "updater" executable file inside these folders: `“~/.thunderbird/updates/“`, `“~/.mozilla-thunderbird-<profile-name>/updates“`
    • or look for FF `"updater"` executable file inside these folders: `“~/.mozilla/updates/“` or `“~/.mozilla/firefox/updates/“`
- and DELETE below mentioned three files from inside above-mentioned specific `"updates"` (or TB/FF app working-directory) sub-folder(s) , especially or atleast the `"updater"` (in macOS/Linux/Unix) or `"updater.exe"` (in Windows) executable file.

  - these three files are related to update and auto-update:
    • `update-settings.ini`,
    • `updater.ini`,
    • `updater.exe` (Windows) or `updater` (macOS/Linux/Unix)
- when `“about:config”`, `pref.js`, policies or regkey, etc setting-up step(s) are done, from then-on TB/FF will-not and should-not (automatically) download any new update installer anymore.

### ADD EXCEPTION RULE INTO UPDATE/VERSION MONITORING APPS:

There are various apps, that can trigger/start/initiate an auto-update process for other apps, (as "updating" techniques/settings are publicly known). Usually these apps obtain version number of your local app(s), in your computer. Then they obtain version number for specific last updated app, either from monitoring app's own remote web-server, or obtain version number from local app developer's remote web-server.

So, if you're using such (monitoring) app(s), then you MUST also have+need to create an EXCEPTION (rule) for Thunderbird (or Firefox) app, inside that/those monitoring app(s), so-that those monitoring apps do-not initiate/trigger an auto-update process.
Example:

- Windows: anti-virus or firewall or security-suite software/tools.
- Linux/Unix app/package update/upgrade/management tool `yum` can update app(s), tool(s), library(s), etc

  - add below exclude line(s) into `yum` config file: `/etc/yum.conf`
    for Thunderbird:
    `exclude=thunderbird*`
    for Firefox:
    `exclude=firefox*`

#### How To Get OLDER Thunderbird(TB) or Firefox(FF) Version:

Below sites contain installer program, integrity-code (hash/checksum) files, etc for different versions and for different languages & localities:

- Thunderbird v68.12.1:
  https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/68.12.1/
- Thunderbird other versions:
  https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/
- Thunderbird stable+latest release:
  https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/
- Firefox (other versions):
  https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
- [Firefox v56.0.2](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0.2/) , [Firefox ESR v52.9.0](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/).
- [Firefox latest+stable version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/)

Portable Editions:

Windows:

- [Portable Thunderbird Legacy (v68)](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird-portable-legacy-68)
- [Portable Thunderbird](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable)
- [Portable Firefox ESR v52.9.0](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-legacy-52)(Gecko without Servo)
- [Portable Firefox v56.0.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2056.0.2/)(Gecko without Servo)
- [Portable Firefox](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)(Gecko with Servo/Quantum)

#### NOTE:

App's devs will release various types of updates. Some "update" are mainly feature related update (feature addition, removal, fix, patch, update, etc), some "update" are mainly app's security related update (security enhancement, improvement, patch, bugfix, etc), etc, etc.
USER / YOU NEED TO INSTALL THE SECURITY RELATED UPDATES, ATLEAST,
as it secures your computer thus in-turn it secures your/user's safety,
provided that, you/user can trust app's devs, that they/devs will release update that is/are actually beneficial for app's USER / YOU, and does not violate/abuse your or any other user's any human-rights.

Comment: I have TB 78.6.0 on macOS and I would like to suppress the "Update is available" popup because updates are too frequent in these days and there is no "skip this update" button. I am annoyed. 
I used the Config Editor but I could not find "app.update.doorhanger" or "app.update.silent" option. I don't see a way to add a new option manually. Is there a secret key sequence for this?

Comment: i have updated above answer, to include How to manually add setting.

Comment: Thank you, @atErik. I added the app.update.silent=true and app.updated.doorhanger=false entries and restarted TB. Unfortunately, TB still shows the update notification dialog. It seems this version of TB doesn't recognize these keys.

Comment: TB devs changing source codes, some newer TB series/versions are not supporting many earlier options !! you may post Feat Request https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi#h=dupes%7CThunderbird (Add option to disable "doorhanger"/auto-update-notice in newer TB), or search there for existing one & select option: you also have this feat request . Earlier TB had this option & some newer TB do-not yet , So i consider it a BUG : Devs ignored to add !! it is UNSAFE: Auto-Update notice appears & by-default keeps "Update" selected !! one mistake/"enter" can do unwanted things, data loss, etc

Comment: This is definitely one of the most awesome answers ever. Thank you so much Erik, at last I removed that annoying green spot on 78.6.1. The way of adding options was a discovery for me.

Comment: btw, @atErik your about:config stuff is no longer relevant it seems. i can not find the door or silent flags.

Comment: As of Thunderbird v.91 (and Firefox), working on Windows 7, none of the GUI, About:Config, or JSON file options have any effect. Only editing the Windows registry works to disable updates. Also it was helpful to see what the GUI will show when you do successfully turn it off, as noted [here](https://www.webnots.com/how-to-disable-automatic-update-in-firefox/).

Comment: Really frustrating that we have to go through all this to keep Thunderbird 68.12.1 around

Comment: TLDR; the 'DISABLE AUTO UPDATE VIA CHANGING THUNDERBIRD UPDATE POLICIES' part did it for me

Answer (score 3):

There is one more useful option in policies.json file - `ManualAppUpdateOnly`. Like `"DisableAppUpdate": true` it allows to disable automatic updates and all annoying "Update available" notifications. And at the same time it still allows to update Thunderbird/Firefox manually through "About Firefox" menu when it is necessary.

The description from mozilla documentation (https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#manualappupdateonly)

> Switch to manual updates only.
>
> If this policy is enabled:
>
> 1. The user will never be prompted to install updates
> 2. Firefox will not check for updates in the background, though it will check automatically when an update UI is displayed (such as the one in the About dialog). This check will be used to show "Update to version X" in the UI, but will not automatically download the update or prompt the user to update in any other way.
> 3. The update UI will work as expected, unlike when using DisableAppUpdate.

Example of `policies.json`:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "ManualAppUpdateOnly": true
  }
}
```

See outstanding answer from @atErik for details how to install this file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64980413/8996217

This option works since Firefox 87 (and since Thunderbird 87 likely) so it would not help with Thunderbird 68 though. Anyway I believe it should be mentioned for completeness

Comment: The most useful option that absolutely SHOULD have been placed in the update config dialog! Thank God Mozilla have left at least that opportunity and blame them for removing that from UI config.